# combing lists in order terraform

Tags: terraform

Can I combine two terraform lists in order ? Please below example. The lists have json below is just an example. To be more specific I am trying to build cloud watch dashboards with multiple widgets (will need multiple metrics) for multiple dynamo db tables. The problem is when I loop through the list of tables the each metric is built per table. So when I open cloudwatch I see same metric for multiple tables ex RCU for table 1, table 2, table 3 then wcu for table 1 , table 2 and table 3. The view I want is multiple metrics for one table ex: rcu for table1 , wcu for table 2 then rcu, wcu for table2 then rcu and wcu for table 3 etc.

locals{

```
body1 = ["1","3"]
body2 = ["2","4"]
```

}

need body3 = ["1","2","3","4"]

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using [`concat`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/concat) and [`sort`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/sort):

```
body3 = sort(concat(local.body1, local.body2))
```

Comment: Should have mentioned both lists have json

Comment: @PaulKatich Update your question to reflect your use case.

Comment: @PaulKatich Reiterating that the lists have json doesn't help. You need to provide details. It's difficult to help you without any information.

Comment: Added more details

Comment: @PaulKatich The exact Terraform code you're having an issue with would be more useful. Please include it as part of your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)